# How to auto update a value without refreshing the whole page

Tags: javascript

I'm setting up a new server, and want to have the remaining balance to be automatically deducted without refreshing the whole page. My problem now is that I have to refresh the whole page for the balance to be updated.

I've already search regarding jQuery but I have no idea on how to use it.

Here's my code:

```
function updateRemaining(field_name, deduction) {
philhealth_deductions[field_name] = deduction;
  var remaining = philhealth_budget;
  for (var i in philhealth_deductions) {
    remaining -= philhealth_deductions[i];
  }

 $("#remaining-philhealth span").html(remaining);
  $(".philhealth_total").html(philhealth_budget-remaining);
}

function updateBalance(currentBalance) {
  $("#remaining-philhealth-balance span").html(currentBalance);
}
```

I wish the balance to be updated without refreshing the page.

Comment: It seems like your balances are calculated client-side. `updateBalance()` should update it without a refresh; you simply need to invoke the function.

Comment: How will I invoke the function?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
function updateRemaining(field_name, deduction) {
philhealth_deductions[field_name] = deduction;
  var remaining = philhealth_budget;
  for (var i in philhealth_deductions) {
    remaining -= philhealth_deductions[i];
  }

// give this id to your span "remaining-philhealth-span"
 document.querySelector('#remaining-philhealth-span').innerHTML = remaining;
 document.querySelector('.philhealth_total').innerHTML = philhealth_budget-remaining
 updateBalance(remaining)
}

function updateBalance(currentBalance) {
// give this id to your span "remaining-philhealth-balance-span"
document.querySelector('#remaining-philhealth-balance-span').innerHTML = currentBalance
}
```